# How to list the files making up a deployed npm package?

Tags: npm, package-managers, file-listing

I'm trying to perform the equivalent of `dpkg -L my_pkg_name` - but with npm. That is, I want to get a list of the deployed files of package `my_pkg_name`.

How do I do that?